# More-than-Two-Dimensional Crosswords from Atomic to Zen

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Following Peter Taylor's answer to
[The smallest crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/the-smallest-crossword/1726?s=1|0.1766#1726)

> >   It's not hard to construct a 1x1 crossword:   . . .

A single-cell crossword could be called *atomic*.

```
               _______
  Surreal:    |10     |     Across          Down           Up          Diagonal
 (no black    |       |    ------------    -----------    --------    --------------
  squares)    |_______|    10. A cross.    10. __-ray.    10. Ten.    10. Two
                                                                          diagonals.


    Zen:       #######                                     Behind
 (one black    #######     ------------    -----------    --------
   square)     #######                                    ?. _____
```

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking" for the "Zen" crossword.

Comment: I don't vote to close, but the question is totally unclear to me. Actually there is no question at all...

Comment: @Deusovi correctly answered the "Surreal" puzzle. Deusovi and kim123 responded appropriately differently to the "Zen" puzzle.  Congratulations!

Comment: @Deusovi This should be reopened. Black squares on crosswords have no content, so a puzzle with just one square has no content if that square is black. I think that's the allusion to 'zen' and fits the OP's comment above. Also, zen is famous for the 'questionless' question(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to "Surreal" is

> X. X is a cross, ten in Roman numerals, and written as two diagonal lines; X-rays are a type of electromagnetic wave.